# How do I implement this TextChanged event handler the MVVM way?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, event-handling, textchanged

How do I implement this event handler the MVVM way?

Other solutions I've seen have you implement a command or a property on the view model.  However, this means every text changed event turns into a command execution or property set.  But this event handler filters out everything except user input.  How would you do that with a command or property binding?

```
private async void SearchBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
   if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
   {
      await this.ViewModel.RefreshAddressSuggestions(sender.Text);    
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://reactiveui.net - there is a sample https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/wpf/getting-started/ReactiveDemo/AppViewModel.cs#L80 which shows how to solve this kind of tasks in reactive way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I implement this TextChanged event handler the MVVM way?

For your requirement, you could bind `Text` property with ViewModel, and check the Text value change to invoke `RefreshAddressSuggestions` method.

```
<AutoSuggestBox Text="{x:Bind SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}"> 


private string searchText;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public string SearchText
{

    get { return searchText; }
    set
    {
        _passWord = value;
        this.ViewModel.RefreshAddressSuggestions(value);
        OnPropertyChanged();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info.  It looks like the way to handle this is through protection against event recursion rather than ignoring TextChanged events based on user input then?

Comment: Yep, you could place above code in your view model, you could also use xaml behavior nuget package to detect `TextChanged` event then invoke a commend in your viewmodel. for more please refer [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/InvokeCommandAction).